# Can you kill people using photos?

Tags: death-note

Not trying to kill L or any other potential enemy of Light using pictures using Misa's eye is a plothole?

I kind of forgotten if the anime or in the manga (I haven't read the manga), has a scene where they wrote someone's name in the Death Note by means of pictures or photos. And if they did, how could Light never thought about using this tactic?

Comment: It's definitely possible to kill someone with only their name and a photo (in the beginning, Light kills a man responsible for a hostage situation that way, after he sees him on TV) but I don't remember why he doesn't have Misa kill L that way. Per the Wiki, a photograph should be sufficient for the Shinigami eyes.

Comment: That is why it is really confusing. The story is very witty yet a simple solution wasn't even tackled or attempted to be used. I guess the author wasn't that great, but you should really give credit to his originality. Coming up with an idea of a notebook with such power is very impressive. Although, it is kind of disappointing specially with his newest work, "Platinum End".

Comment: It might have something to do with Light wanting to avoid suspicion: note that Light also doesn't have Misa kill L immediately. I don't think I could offer a better answer though, without starting the manga (as I've been thinking of doing lately) or rewatching.

Comment: I guess, author might have came up with this idea, but as light refuses to have shinigami eyes, same concept could have been applied for this photograph concept too..

Answer (score 4):

You can kill people using photo or video. But getting L picture is not that easy. (Pictures taken from chapter 30)

[image: chapter 30][image: chapter 30]

Later Misa met Light and L together and she knew L real name. Light could ask Misa to kill him or ask her his real name but Misa was arrested short after they parted. But even if Light know his real name he didn't want to do that immediately because Light was very cautious about killing L. (Pictures taken from chapter 19)

[image: page 9 chapter 19]

He was in deep thought about it but he conclude he couldn't kill L without getting suspected by the police. (click to enlarge picture)

[image: page 15 chapter 19]
[image: page 16 chapter 19]
[image: page 17 chapter 19]

Later when he learn that he's the real L. He still didn't want to kill him and just want to take it slow and find out about everything before taking any action.

Comment: I think it is ridiculuous to think that way: "I need not to harm him or else I'll be suspected, so I'll learn more first so that I will know everything about this guy who's been trying to literally kill me". It was very exaggerated to say the least, wouldn't it make sense to find a way to kill him as soon as possible. He is his greatest threat, he should find every way as soon as possible to kill him, but instead he just let his greatest enemy near him "in order to learn more" although L should have been the one who should not know more about him since it will point to him as Kira at the end.

Comment: Also, if he could not get a hold of a picture of L (I doubt it though, there's too many ways to get one), he should have taken action at least to anyone who's helping L.

Comment: One of Light's very lacking of action, is to attemp to kill them using photos. It could have been the most significant action he could have taken, in order to pracically make L surrender, since he won't understand why people around him are dying even though their faces and names weren't revealed.

Overall, Death Note is a very thrilling anime. But I think it was the kind of a show where you would think a genius must have made this at first, and then you reexamine it and you'll see a lot of plotholes and coincidental set of events that the author made to justify the holes in their story.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, he could've killed L if he did have an image of him. But L was too cautious, he didn't reveal his own or Watari's face(unless absolutely necessary). It wasn't like Light could've found pictures of L lying around in his father's computer.

Also he couldn't have taken them himself as every person entering the headquarters was supposed to enter without any electronic gadgets(if I remember correctly.)

The only plot hole in my opinion is that he could've obtained an image from the bystanders that witnessed his tennis match against L. Obviously, the students would've recorded and/or taken photos of the match.

Comment: Nah, I don't think it is the only plothole. Light can easily take a picture of L. Even with killing everyone who's helping L would be enough, if ever there will never/would be no picture of him. 

For me, there are so many plotholes, like other mediocre anime, because if you really examine each rule and how or when it was introduced, it is very clear that most rules are just there to cover some holes in the story. 

And one of the biggest ass-pull rule is "A person can shorten his/her own life by using the note." making him able to do virtually anything, and still get away with it.